# Cannot find the path specified when attempting to rename certain files in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, directory-structure, file-rename

I am attempting to write a script that would rename all my tv show files I have on an external HDD. Using regular expressions, it should find the season and episode number for each episode then rename the file following a certain format which I've specified in my code below. The problem I'm facing is that I keep getting the following error when I run it.

[Here is the error I'm encountering](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfipU.png)

And here is my code:

```
import os, re

file_name_regex = re.compile(r'[s]\d{2}[e]\d{2}', re.IGNORECASE)


root_name_regex = re.compile(r'\\?(.+?)\\|(.+)')

listing = os.walk('E:\\TV Shows')
for root, directories, files in listing:
    for f in files:
        if re.search(file_name_regex, f):
            matched_file_name = file_name_regex.search(f)

            #Gives you the season / episode numbers
            season_episode_identify = matched_file_name.group()

            #Gives you the name of the TV show
            path_list = root_name_regex.findall(root)
            tv_show_name = path_list[2][0]

            new_file_path = os.path.join(root, tv_show_name + ' ' + season_episode_identify)
            old_file_path = os.path.join(root, tv_show_name, f)

            print(f'Renaming "{old_file_path}" to "{new_file_path}"...')
            os.rename(old_file_path, new_file_path)
```

Thanks in advance for any help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit messy. Consider using the [pathlib module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html). You can do something like

```
from pathlib import Path

path_root = Path('E:\\TV Shows')
for path_file in path_root.rglob('*.*'):
    file_name_regex.search(path_file.name)
    ....
```

The parsing of the path might also be done using a single re-pattern.

The error you get is probably due to a missing sub directory. You cannot move a file to a non existing directory. You have to create it beforehand. Using pathlib you can do something like

```
new_file_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
```

But you can also use `os.mkdir()`